# arm inline gcc error : expeced a ")"

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, inline, ds-5

I am using the following code to perform multiplication using DS5 ARM C Compiler 5. The compiler throws build errors stating  expected a ")"

```
static __inline int32_t multiply(int32_t x, int32_t y)
{
    __asm volatile(
            "mul %0, %1, %2\n\t"
            : "=a"(y)                   // error pointed to this line
            : "r"(x), "a"(y));


    return y;
}
```

Note: target --cpu is armV7a. Is there any way to overcome this error?

Comment: Compiles fine here using gcc. Is the compiler you use really gcc?

Comment: armcc is not GCC. It may support [_some_ GNU features](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0472k/chr1359124965274.html), but GCC's extended asm is not one of them.

Comment: I think armcc doesn't support extended assembly http://ds.arm.com/developer-resources/tutorials/using-inline-assembly-code-to-improve-code-efficiency/